# How to use a UpdatePanel to set a labels text to a SqlDataSource value every 5 seconds

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel

I need to use an updatepanel to set a labels text to a sqldatasource value every 5 seconds.  I don't really know how to use the updatepanel, I also can't find a way to run a script every 5 seconds.

Does anybody have any ideas for this?

I'm using vb.net and asp.net.

Comment: Do you have to use an UpdatePanel? Because it'll work a heck of a lot better with ajax.

Comment: use setTimeout and regular ajax is possible.  Otherwise you can use setTimeout to press a button or something to post-back the update panel

Comment: Thanks, I might use your idea tster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx)

[TimerControl](http://TimerControl)

Comment: I'll be using a TimerControl.